# show a list of file with a specific extension in PHP

Tags: php, list

I have this script and is working very good, now, I need to show just a list of an extension file, like ".TXT"...

if I run this code, I will have all list of all file, but I need to show just a specific extension...

I'm new in PHP, and I try to add `$file != ".TXT"` but doesn't work...

Thank you very much :)

```
 <?php 

 $User = $_GET['User'];

   $dir    = "myfolder/$User";

        if (is_dir($dir)) { if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {

            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {                
                clearstatcache();
                if(is_file($dir."/".$file )) {    
                    echo '';             
                    echo $file;
                    echo "|";                    
                    echo "DATE:" . date ("F d, Y H:i:s", filemtime(utf8_decode($dir."/".$file)));
                    echo "|";
                }                
            }            

            //echo "<br>";
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }   
   ?>
```

Comment: hint: [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: Another hint: `pathinfo()`

Comment: foreach (glob("D:/dir/*.txt") as $filename) {
    // do something with $filename
} displays only txt files

Comment: If files are not created by yourself you should probably think about using mime_content_type since the file's extension could differ from the real content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use php's [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

```
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (strtolower($ext) == '.txt') {
// PUT YOUR CODE HERE
```